# Data not going into Table (mySQL) (no errors coming up)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I'm building a website that allows people to report problems to others, and thought it would be useful to store each problem in a table. However when I run the code the data isn't entered, when I turned on errors for mysql with  `or die(mysql_error());` at the end, I got nothing. just a white page.

Here is my insert statement in full. Is there any reason as to why it might not work, or why errors just don't show up?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO reported_problems (time, Full Name, E-mail, Phone Number, House Number, First Line, City, Postcode, Problem Type, Description, Urgency) VALUES(now(),'$fullname','$tenantemail','$phonenumber','$housenumber','$streetname','$city','$postcode','$typeofproblem','$probdesc','$severity_desc')";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Some of your column names contains spaces as well as the hyphen in `E-mail`, therefore they need to be wrapped in backticks. It's best to use underscores.

Answer (score 4):

You have spaces in your column identifiers. This can be solved by wrapping your column identifiers in ticks:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO reported_problems (`time`, `Full Name`, `E-mail`, `Phone Number`, `House Number`, `First Line`, `City`, `Postcode`, `Problem Type`, `Description`, `Urgency`) VALUES(now(),'$fullname','$tenantemail','$phonenumber','$housenumber','$streetname','$city','$postcode','$typeofproblem','$probdesc','$severity_desc')";
```

FYI, having column names that are keywords/function names, contain dashes, and with spaces are both discouraged. Use camel case or underscores if possible.

Comment: I was going to post the same answer...time is a reserved word and column names problem xD

Comment: I quote from [`MySQL.com`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) *"MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them."* --- What do they mean by "unquoted"?

Comment: @Fred-ii- You'll notice I took that part out as you were typing this as `time` does fall into that category. I just left a note that using it is a bad idea. :)

Comment: Ah, Ok John. Yet, I tend to think that it's mainly because of the spaces in some of the column names and the hyphen in `E-mail` @JohnConde

Comment: WoW, i had no idea time was a reserved keyword, I'll remember that one for in the future. Also, as a general rule of thumb, do you just backtick all of your columns for good habit?

Comment: By the way thanks for the quick and accurate answers!

Comment: Added my **+1** contribution ;-)

Comment: @Duenna It's a good habit as it prevents things like this from slipping through. But it isn't hugely important to do in general.